# pip install azureml-sdk with latest patches to underlying libraries

Tags: python, pip, azure-machine-learning-service

How do I upgrade `azureml-sdk` such that the newest release of `azureml-core`, `1.1.5.5`, is installed? 
If `azureml-sdk` is not installed, `pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk` will install `azureml-core==1.1.5.5`. If it is already installed, then it won't.

```
$ pip list --format=freeze | grep 'azureml-core'`
> azureml-core==1.1.5.1
$ pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk[interpret,notebooks]
$ pip list --format=freeze | grep 'azureml-core'`
> azureml-core==1.1.5.1
```

Comment: the challenge is that `azureml-sdk` is a conglomerate of packages. two days ago, a sub-package, `azureml-core` was updated to `1.1.5.5` https://pypi.org/project/azureml-core/#history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the eager strategy to force an upgrade of requirements:

```
pip install -U --upgrade-strategy eager azureml-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

run `pip install --upgrade azureml-core==1.1.5.5`.

`azureml-sdk`'s `metadata.json` (as of `1.1.5.1`) lists the following requirements:

```
azureml-core (==1.1.5.*)
azureml-dataprep[fuse] (==1.3.2)
azureml-pipeline (==1.1.5.*)
azureml-train (==1.1.5.*)
azureml-train-automl-client (==1.1.5.*)
```

So if the SDK version `1.1.5.1` was already installed, then `azureml-core==1.1.5.1` meets the SDK's requirements and it won't be upgraded.